# convert .pem to jks with out key file

Tags: java, openssl, keystore, keytool

i am trying to convert .pem file to .jks but i am unable to do it. the `cert.pem` has passphrase only but not any key file.

i tried this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in cert.pem -out cert.p12

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass login1 -destkeystore trustStore.jks
```

and i got :

`Import command completed:  0 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled`.

and created `trustStore.jks` is empty.

how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Import PEM into p12 type keystore

`$ keytool -importcert -keystore cert.p12 -storepass "password123" -file cert.pem -alias "cert"`

Convert p12 keystore into JKS keystore

`$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore cert.jks -deststoretype jks`

View keystore to validate type

`$ keytool -list -v -keystore cert.jks`

Answer (score 0):

When you have a certificate file (.pem file), you usually add it to a keystore, but not convert it.

In order to add a certificate to a keystore (new/existing), you can run this `keytool` command:

> keytool -importcert -keystore "KEYSTORE_FILE" -storepass "KEYSTORE_PASSWORD" -file "CERTIFICATE_FILE" -alias "CERTIFICATE_ALIAS"